# How to analyze and solve the lag problem of Spring-Kafka Consumer?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka to build my consumer. The consumer seems to be working fine, but at most time, it lags behind by about 1000 records, sometimes can reach 3000 records. I checked the printed INFO, the consumer frequently calls KafkaConsumer.seek(), and it will seek to the same offset for several times. I'm not sure whether it is normal. Is there a good way to find the main bottleneck that causes the lag problem?

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig(){
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
    }

    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> factory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory
    ){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Edit:
I find the problem. The lag problem is caused by too many times of retry. I disabled the retry after exception and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **seek()** function, the KAFKA API lets you see seek a specific offest, instead of using **seekToBeginning(TopicPartition tp)** and **seekToEnd(TopicPartition tp)**.

When a consumer starts or when new partitionsare assigned, it uses **seek()** to a specific offset and start processing the message.

So in your case, your consumer may seeking a particular offset and skipping events (go back a few messages or skip ahead a few messages), and also may not be having better commit process in place, hence, you could see the consumer lags.

Find the reason/use-case, why you need the seek in your code. You can even remove and test it once.